FileManager.default.copyItem throws error "The file doesn't exist"
I am a beginner at SwiftUI and my practice code repo is here. I am trying to use LLMFarm Core to create a local LLM. While trying to run this code
try FileManager.default.copyItem(atPath: temporaryURL.path, toPath: fileURL.path)
I'm getting the error which I'm guessing comes from the temporaryURL variable:
Error: The file “CFNetworkDownload_rr8uC6.tmp” doesn’t exist.
This is what my code function looks like
status = "downloading"
print("Downloading model \(modelName) from \(modelUrl)")
guard let url = URL(string: modelUrl) else { return }
let fileURL = getFileURLFormPathStr(dir:"models",filename: filename)
downloadTask = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url) { temporaryURL, response, error in
    if let error = error {
        return
    }
    guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, (200...299).contains(response.statusCode) else {
        print("Server error!")
        return
    }
    do {
        if let temporaryURL = temporaryURL {
            try FileManager.default.copyItem(atPath: temporaryURL.path, toPath: fileURL.path)

I tried to use try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: temporaryURL, to: fileURL) instead but that didn't work either.
I also made sure I have added all the entitlements and info plist properties that seemed to be needed using the LLM farm sample. Any help will be greatly appreciated. The repository should be easily cloneable and you can test it on your local computers. I tried it on my local personal device and M1 computer, but got the same error
Edit: I also tried to add if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path) above if let temporaryURL = temporaryURL, so the file exists but I do not know why my code does not reflect that.
Edit2: Here's the value of the temporaryURL file:///Users/salman/Library/Containers/com.guinmoon.LLMFarm23/Data/tmp/CFNetworkDownload_QfLexg.tmp
and here's the value of the fileURL
file:///Users/salman/Library/Containers/com.guinmoon.LLMFarm23/Data/Documents/models/tinyllama-1.1b-chat-v1.0.Q4_K_M.gguf

@JoakimDanielson his modelUrl using URL(string:) is referencing the url from his AIView correctly as you can see here in the DownloadButton view https://github.com/salmallick/SwiftUIBasics/blob/a8c89f81807d51ec424ccfe77aa11449214603ec/FirstApp/FirstApp/DownloadButton.swift#L27C37-L27C45

what happens if you print(String(contentsOf: temporaryURL))?

@timbretimbre when I checked, it retuned the full path of the file, so it was something like file://…tmp/CFNetworkDownload_rr8uC6.tmp

String(contentsOf: temporaryURL) is supposed to print the contents of the file. I wonder if the issue is that file is empty for example.

@Saamer I know, I had already removed my comment. I got the different urls mixed up.

@timbretimbre this is the error we get when we run your code Error: The file “CFNetworkDownload_QfLexg.tmp” couldn’t be opened because the text encoding of its contents can’t be determined. I had to do a try before putting that line of code under print, and then it threw an exception. I ran that code in my sample and in his code (where it works)

It looks like FileManager.copyItem(atPath:toPath:) is throwing a misleading error.
The temporary file does indeed exist at temporaryURL. However, the destination directory, file:///Users/salman/Library/Containers/com.guinmoon.LLMFarm23/Data/Documents/models, does not exist. Since copyItem(atPath:toPath:) does not automatically create directories needed for new files, the attempt to copy the file to fileURL is failing.
Before beginning the download, create the models directory by calling try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: fileURL.deletingLastPathComponent(), withIntermediateDirectories: true), and the copy operation should succeed.

I had a case in the past where I was trying to use copyItem(atPath:toPath:) where the destination path didn't already exist and the error I got clearly showed the correct error. It will be interesting to see if the OP indicates that the models folder in Documents does or does not exist and whether this answer is in fact correct or not.

I downloaded and ran the project he linked to. The models directory was missing, and this fixed it. I can’t figure out why this error is being thrown though, because like you, I’ve always seen the correct error in the past.

@ConfusedByCode how did you figure out that was the issue?

I recently implemented a feature that involved copying files to a new directory, so FileManager was fresh in my mind. When I didn't see the target directory created in the code posted in the question I looked for it in the linked repo, and when I couldn't find it there, I decided to download and run the app to investigate. I opened Finder windows for the source and target directories so I could quickly see the files & directories. After seeing the copy fail, I manually created the "models" directory, and then the copy succeeded.
